# How do I set initial values for extra fields on a Django Model Formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, default, formset

Given the following models:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ChildModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    weight = models.FloatField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey("ParentModel")
```

And the following ModelForm that has some extra fields for ChildModel:

```
class ChildBalancingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    min_weight = forms.FloatField(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0, required=True, label="Min Weight")
    max_weight = forms.FloatField(min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0, required=True, label="Max Weight")
    class Meta:
        model = ChildModel
        fields = []
```

I have a parent model that has many children.  I need to use some math to balance the weights of the children (with some bounds on the minimum and maximum weight of each child).  So, I am trying to create a formset that allows a user to enter a min and a max weight for each child to submit for rebalancing.  I want to specify a default minimum weight, and a default maximum weight in said form.  Thus, I have the following in my view:

```
# code to load up the parent whose children are being rebalanced..
# code to set a value for default_min_weight and default_max_weight
# code to get the number of children of said parent, num_children

initial_data = [{"min_weight": default_min_weight, "max_weight": default_max_weight},] * num_children
BalancingFormSet = modelformset_factory(ChildModel, form=ChildBalancingForm, extra=0, can_delete=False, min_num=num_children, max_num=num_children)
formset = BalancingFormSet(queryset=parent.childmodel_set.all(), initial=initial_data)
```

However when I output the form, the default values I specified for min_weight and max_weight do not show (the fields are just empty).  What is the proper way to specify initial values for those extra fields in my formset?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `ModelFormSet`s redefine the `initial` parameter to apply to the extra forms. However, source-diving reveals that we can just re-add it under a different name:

```
# code to load up the parent whose children are being rebalanced..
# code to set a value for default_min_weight and default_max_weight
# code to get the number of children of said parent, num_children

initial_data = [{"min_weight": default_min_weight, "max_weight": default_max_weight},] * num_children

BalancingFormSetBase = modelformset_factory(ChildModel, form=ChildBalancingForm, extra=0, can_delete=False, min_num=num_children, max_num=num_children)

class BalancingFormSet(BalancingFormSetBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial_forms_initial = kwargs.pop("initial_forms_initial", None)
        super(BalancingFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not initial_forms_initial is None:
            self.initial = initial_forms_initial

formset = BalancingFormSet(queryset=parent.childmodel_set.all(), initial_forms_initial=initial_data)
```

I (sloppily) tested equivalent code on Django 1.8, and it didn't interfere with instance attributes - I didn't check what happens if you have `extra` set to something that isn't `0`, though.

Starting with 1.9, overriding the new `get_form_kwargs` method may be more robust as it doesn't assume that we can overwrite the `initial` attribute without unwanted consequences.

Of course, if you have this pattern more than once, it might make sense to put this `__init__` definition into a base class or a mixin - however, for clarity and simplicity, I'm not doing this here.